# Firebase Authentication is not sending text message

Tags: android, android-studio

I have already registered my app and my phone number in the Fire base console but I am not getting any text or error message. If I enter the OTP code manually then its working but I am not getting the code via text message. I have already enabled the text permission for the app in the emulator. I am able to successfully connect to Fire base via Android studio. Please let me know the reason for this issue.

```
https://github.com/probelalkhan/firebase-phone-authentication
```

Added Below Lines in AndroidManifestFiles

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Error:

```
2018-11-20 01:36:18.844 1668-1698/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=net.test.firebasephoneauth/.VerifyPhoneActivity (has extras)} from uid 10104

    --------- beginning of main
2018-11-20 01:36:17.931 2178-10055/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:36:18.859 1432-4162/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 31835443 , only wrote 31834800
2018-11-20 01:36:18.904 10040-10171/net.test.firebasephoneauth V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 11948
2018-11-20 01:36:18.905 10040-10171/net.test.firebasephoneauth V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2018-11-20 01:36:18.933 10040-10171/net.test.firebasephoneauth V/FA: Activity paused, time: 29422390
2018-11-20 01:36:18.948 1668-1684/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-20 01:36:18.948 1668-1684/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
2018-11-20 01:36:18.974 10040-10171/net.test.firebasephoneauth D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=11948, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-183638583716897559}]
2018-11-20 01:36:18.987 10040-10040/net.test.firebasephoneauth V/FA: onActivityCreated
2018-11-20 01:36:19.131 10040-10040/net.test.firebasephoneauth W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@efe3c56
2018-11-20 01:36:19.162 10040-10171/net.test.firebasephoneauth V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2018-11-20 01:36:19.223 10040-10171/net.test.firebasephoneauth D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-183638583716897559, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=VerifyPhoneActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-183638583716897556}]
2018-11-20 01:36:19.223 2432-3183/com.google.android.gms W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneVerificationSession] PhoneVerificationSession constructor
2018-11-20 01:36:19.233 2432-10045/com.google.android.gms W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess starts
2018-11-20 01:36:19.292 2432-8949/com.google.android.gms I/AuthChimeraService: Executing request: ProxyRequest[ url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyAq5g11wtgp1fFJML8lBp8xKVMDiLx-Nio, method: 1 ]
2018-11-20 01:36:19.317 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [DeviceKeyStore] Cannot load key: Device key file not found.
2018-11-20 01:36:19.354 10040-10171/net.test.firebasephoneauth V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2018-11-20 01:36:19.355 10040-10171/net.test.firebasephoneauth V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2018-11-20 01:36:19.355 10040-10171/net.test.firebasephoneauth V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 29422653
2018-11-20 01:36:19.362 1537-1537/? I/DrmHal: makeDrmFactories: factory instance default is Remote
2018-11-20 01:36:19.364 1537-1537/? I/DrmHal: makeDrmFactories: factory instance widevine is Remote
2018-11-20 01:36:19.375 1437-3345/? D/WVCdm: Instantiating CDM.
2018-11-20 01:36:19.378 1437-3345/? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::QueryStatus
2018-11-20 01:36:19.387 1437-10191/? I/WVCdm: Level3 Library 4464 May 19 2017 16:59:48
2018-11-20 01:36:19.395 1437-3345/? I/WVCdm: L3 Initialized. Trying L1.
2018-11-20 01:36:19.397 1437-3345/? W/WVCdm: Could not load liboemcrypto.so. Falling back to L3.  dlopen failed: library "liboemcrypto.so" not found
2018-11-20 01:36:19.397 1437-3345/? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::OpenSession
2018-11-20 01:36:19.398 1437-10193/? I/WVCdm: Level3 Library 4464 May 19 2017 16:59:48
2018-11-20 01:36:19.416 1437-3345/? I/WVCdm: L3 Initialized. Trying L1.
2018-11-20 01:36:19.416 1437-3345/? W/WVCdm: Could not load liboemcrypto.so. Falling back to L3.  dlopen failed: library "liboemcrypto.so" not found
2018-11-20 01:36:19.416 1437-3345/? D/WVCdm: CryptoSession::Open: Lock: requested_security_level: Default
2018-11-20 01:36:19.425 1437-3345/? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::QueryOemCryptoSessionId
2018-11-20 01:36:19.430 1437-3345/? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::GenerateKeyRequest
2018-11-20 01:36:19.430 1437-3345/? D/WVCdm: PrepareKeyRequest: nonce=828407147
2018-11-20 01:36:19.519 1440-2415/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 14749696
2018-11-20 01:36:19.538 1440-2415/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) HwBinder:1440_2 identical 1 line
2018-11-20 01:36:19.555 1440-2415/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 14749696
2018-11-20 01:36:19.625 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2018-11-20 01:36:19.625 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.625 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):13)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.625 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: setsockopt failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.625 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:     at libcore.io.Linux.setsockoptTimeval(Native Method)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.625 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.setsockoptTimeval(ForwardingOs.java:175)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.629 10040-10171/net.test.firebasephoneauth D/FA: Connected to remote service
2018-11-20 01:36:19.635 10040-10171/net.test.firebasephoneauth V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
2018-11-20 01:36:19.645 10040-10070/net.test.firebasephoneauth D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe4d055a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe4d03420)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.719 10040-10070/net.test.firebasephoneauth D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe4d055a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe4d03420)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.721 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=user_engagement(_e),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=11948, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-183638583716897559}]
2018-11-20 01:36:19.742 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2018-11-20 01:36:19.748 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.748 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):13)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.748 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: setsockopt failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.748 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:     at libcore.io.Linux.setsockoptTimeval(Native Method)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.748 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.setsockoptTimeval(ForwardingOs.java:175)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.765 10040-10070/net.test.firebasephoneauth D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe4d055a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe4d03420)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.780 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: user_engagement(_e), 68
2018-11-20 01:36:19.781 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='net.test.firebasephoneauth', name='user_engagement(_e)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=11948, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-183638583716897559}]}
2018-11-20 01:36:19.799 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 811734
2018-11-20 01:36:19.806 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
2018-11-20 01:36:19.825 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with GcmTaskService
2018-11-20 01:36:19.831 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Scheduling task with Gcm. time: 811734
2018-11-20 01:36:19.834 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key: 
    java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
        at hnl.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):11)
        at hnl.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):64)
        at hnl.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):22)
        at hnj.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):2)
        at hnj.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):12)
        at wwt.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):3)
        at cgv.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):5)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:627)
        at djf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):3)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.834 2178-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [DeviceKeyStore] Cannot load key: Device key file not found.
2018-11-20 01:36:19.849 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 128
2018-11-20 01:36:19.867 2178-5168/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
2018-11-20 01:36:19.893 1668-1692/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed net.test.firebasephoneauth/.VerifyPhoneActivity: +968ms
2018-11-20 01:36:19.896 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-183638583716897559, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=VerifyPhoneActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-183638583716897556}]
2018-11-20 01:36:19.911 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: screen_view(_vs), 104
2018-11-20 01:36:19.911 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='net.test.firebasephoneauth', name='screen_view(_vs)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-183638583716897559, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=VerifyPhoneActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-183638583716897556}]}
2018-11-20 01:36:19.911 1668-1809/system_process W/Binder: Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY
    java.lang.Throwable
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:752)
        at android.app.assist.AssistStructure$ParcelTransferReader.fetchData(AssistStructure.java:407)
        at android.app.assist.AssistStructure$ParcelTransferReader.go(AssistStructure.java:343)
        at android.app.assist.AssistStructure.ensureData(AssistStructure.java:2110)
        at com.android.server.autofill.Session$1.send(Session.java:227)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.reportAssistContextExtras(ActivityManagerService.java:13272)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2472)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2919)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.915 10040-10040/net.test.firebasephoneauth I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2876 bytes, containing 1 windows, 9 views
2018-11-20 01:36:19.917 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 811616
2018-11-20 01:36:19.937 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
2018-11-20 01:36:19.965 2432-4176/com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2018-11-20 01:36:19.965 2432-4176/com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.965 2432-4176/com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):13)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.965 2432-4176/com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: setsockopt failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.965 2432-4176/com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt:     at libcore.io.Linux.setsockoptTimeval(Native Method)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.965 2432-4176/com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.setsockoptTimeval(ForwardingOs.java:175)
2018-11-20 01:36:19.970 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with GcmTaskService
2018-11-20 01:36:19.977 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Scheduling task with Gcm. time: 811616
2018-11-20 01:36:19.994 1668-4936/system_process I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2780 bytes, containing 1 windows, 9 views
2018-11-20 01:36:20.009 1668-1686/system_process D/AutofillUI: destroySaveUiUiThread(): already destroyed
2018-11-20 01:36:20.015 2432-10172/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 119
2018-11-20 01:36:20.029 1778-1778/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/zygote: Deoptimizing java.lang.Object ji.put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) due to JIT inline cache
2018-11-20 01:36:20.037 2178-5168/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
2018-11-20 01:36:20.099 2432-4176/com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2018-11-20 01:36:20.100 2432-4176/com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2018-11-20 01:36:20.100 2432-4176/com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):13)
2018-11-20 01:36:20.100 2432-4176/com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: setsockopt failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
2018-11-20 01:36:20.100 2432-4176/com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt:     at libcore.io.Linux.setsockoptTimeval(Native Method)
2018-11-20 01:36:20.100 2432-4176/com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.setsockoptTimeval(ForwardingOs.java:175)
2018-11-20 01:36:20.100 1778-4144/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/native: streaming-decoder.cc:1550 Failed to unload dynamic LM.
2018-11-20 01:36:20.105 1778-10198/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin W/DynamicPruner: getPruneRequest() : Unexpected LM type: 4
2018-11-20 01:36:20.231 2432-3183/com.google.android.gms I/Icing: IndexChimeraService.getServiceInterface callingPackage=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin componentName=null serviceId=66
2018-11-20 01:36:20.257 2432-8949/com.google.android.gms I/AuthChimeraService: Executing send connection operation
2018-11-20 01:36:20.258 2432-3179/com.google.android.gms W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneVerificationSession] onCodeSent
2018-11-20 01:36:20.265 10040-10040/net.test.firebasephoneauth I/PhoneAuthProvider: Sms auto retrieval timed-out.
2018-11-20 01:36:20.282 1441-6154/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
2018-11-20 01:36:20.282 1441-6154/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
2018-11-20 01:36:20.283 1441-6154/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
2018-11-20 01:36:20.283 1441-6154/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
2018-11-20 01:36:20.284 1441-6154/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
2018-11-20 01:36:20.284 1441-6154/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
2018-11-20 01:36:20.346 1432-4162/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 31906197 , only wrote 31906080
2018-11-20 01:36:20.594 2432-10144/com.google.android.gms I/Icing: Usage reports ok 1, Failed Usage reports 0, indexed 0, rejected 0, imm upload false
2018-11-20 01:36:21.426 1448-1448/? I/boot-pipe: done populating /dev/random
2018-11-20 01:36:22.075 1432-1593/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 32071052 , only wrote 31988880
2018-11-20 01:36:22.937 2178-9193/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:36:24.784 10040-10171/net.test.firebasephoneauth V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2018-11-20 01:36:27.954 2178-9193/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:36:30.374 1778-10198/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/IcingDataProcessor: getIMEUpdates() failed: Status{statusCode=TIMEOUT, resolution=null}
2018-11-20 01:36:32.940 2178-9193/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:36:35.424 1668-1684/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-20 01:36:35.424 1668-1684/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
2018-11-20 01:36:37.958 2178-10055/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:36:39.403 1668-1684/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-20 01:36:39.403 1668-1684/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
2018-11-20 01:36:39.406 1668-1688/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2018-11-20 01:36:43.954 2178-9193/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:36:53.971 2178-9193/com.google.android.gms.persistent I/chatty: uid=10014(com.google.android.gms) lowpool[38] identical 2 lines
2018-11-20 01:36:58.967 2178-9193/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:37:00.018 1668-1684/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-20 01:37:00.018 1668-1684/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
2018-11-20 01:37:00.030 1793-2030/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe4d056c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe4d039e0)
2018-11-20 01:37:03.973 2178-9193/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:37:08.990 2178-10055/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:37:13.985 2178-9193/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:37:19.000 2178-10055/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:37:19.004 1668-1684/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-20 01:37:19.004 1668-1684/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
2018-11-20 01:37:19.325 2432-3183/com.google.android.gms W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneVerificationSession] PhoneVerificationSession terminated
2018-11-20 01:37:19.368 2432-10045/com.google.android.gms W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess ends
2018-11-20 01:37:21.427 1448-1448/? I/boot-pipe: done populating /dev/random
2018-11-20 01:37:24.011 2178-10055/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:37:34.021 2178-10055/com.google.android.gms.persistent I/chatty: uid=10014(com.google.android.gms) lowpool[39] identical 2 lines
2018-11-20 01:37:39.028 2178-10055/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
2018-11-20 01:37:39.436 1668-1684/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-20 01:37:39.436 1668-1684/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
2018-11-20 01:37:39.463 1668-1684/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-20 01:37:39.463 1668-1684/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
2018-11-20 01:37:39.498 1668-1684/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-20 01:37:39.498 1668-1684/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
2018-11-20 01:37:44.051 2178-10055/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10014):IndoorOutdoorProducer, vrsn=13280000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 2178). Was: 3 for 57, account#-517948760#
```

Answer (score 3):

Please add your SHA1 key in firebase console in order to receive OTP

Comment: I added SHA1 key but I am getting timed-out error now . 2018-11-20 01:24:38.433 2432-8949/com.google.android.gms I/AuthChimeraService: Executing send connection operation
2018-11-20 01:24:38.434 2432-3179/com.google.android.gms W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneVerificationSession] onCodeSent
2018-11-20 01:24:38.443 10040-10040/net.joshva.firebasephoneauth I/PhoneAuthProvider: Sms auto retrieval timed-out.

Comment: are you using latest firebase version?

Comment: Yes. implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'

Comment: try this https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth

Comment: Even this project is not working for me. I am not getting text message thats the problem on both the project.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase console -> Authentication -> Phone 
 - Remove your phone from "test devices" section.